# Permission to use comments

Tags: discussion

I am writing a bible article about Ezekiel 28.  I found a good comment related to chapter 28.  I was wondering of the comments were copyright.  If so, how do I get permission to use the comments?

Comment: Do you mean the comments on questions/answers on this site? You can always quote them, just like everything else, but remember to attribute them to the author. If you just copy them then that would be plagiarism. And for the record, all user submitted content on this site is copyrighted, but released under the Creative Commons Attribution ShareAlike license, as indicated in the page footer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and of what to do.  Do you have an example of giving credit to the author of the comment?  I am new about publishing a book, so I don't want to do anything wrong.  I am new on this forum also.  Thank you again.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation) has lots of information about citations. Your publisher probably has a recommended or even required citation style, so you should ask them.

Comment: This is my first time in doing anything like this.  Thank you for your help.